# adding and removing text field with associated number input values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of number input fields, labeled small & medium, and a set of div's with the label small and medium.
When you add a number to the small number input field a text input should insertAfter the div labeled small. When you subtract a number from the small number input field, the text input field that was recently added should be removed. the adding and removing of the text input should be the last one in the list.

when you remove a text field it should only remove the text field with the associated size.

Right now my script is adding text input fields at the top of the newly generated inputs (I know that it is happening this way because my script says to insertAfter the label, so it will always add a input at the top, but I don't want that).

Also right now it is removing the very last input that is present and not the very last input of the associated size.

[Code here](http://jsfiddle.net/7PhJZ/41/)

It is easier to see what i am talking about when you fill in the inputs (a,b,c after adding them to see which one is being removed and where they are being added).

This is complicated for me to explain in words, but when you look at the fiddle, it may become more clear. if you need me to explain something else, please ask.

script:

```
$('.product-quantity').each(function() {
    $(this).data('val', this.value);
}).on('change', function () {
            var val = $(this).val(),
                    old = $(this).data('val'),
                    ele = $(this).closest('[id^="product"]').find
            ('[data-size="'+this.name+'"]'),
                    inc = val >= old;

            if (inc) {
                $('<input/>', {'class': 'name-number-field'} ).insertAfter(ele);
            }else {
                $('.name-number-field', ele.parent()).first().remove();
            }

            $(this).data('val', this.value);
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe

```
$('.product-quantity').each(function () {
    $(this).data('val', this.value);
}).on('change', function () {
    var val = $(this).val(),
        old = $(this).data('val'),
        ele = $(this).closest('[id^="product"]').find('[data-size="' + this.name + '"]'),
        inc = val >= old;

    if (inc) {
        $('<input/>', {
            'class': 'name-number-field'
        }).insertAfter(ele.nextUntil('div').last().length ? ele.nextUntil('div').last() : ele);
    } else {
        ele.nextUntil('div').last().remove();
    }

    $(this).data('val', this.value);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7PhJZ/44/)

Comment: your fiddle works wonderfully! I am going to try and implement it to my project now. and see what I come up with. thank you

Comment: in my project I changed the newly created input:class:name-number-field to a div:class:name-number-field. when I try to change <input/> to <div/> in the if (inc) it breaks the remove. what is telling the remove that it is an input?

Comment: It's using nextUntil('div') to get all the next elements that aren't DIV's, so when using DIV's there's nothing to know what elements where inserted or not, as they are all DIV's

Comment: oh ok I see. is there another element/container I can use other than div or input? because you see I changed it to a div so that I could insert html inside the div and then add and remove the div with inserted html in it. I did this by creating a variable :                         input = $('<div/> ', {'class': 'name-number-field', 'type': 'text'}).html('<input class="name-field" name=​"name" placeholder="Name" type=​"text">​<input class="number-field" name=​"number" placeholder=​# type=​"text">​') and then I did this : if (inc) {
                    $(input).insertAfter

Comment: @anmaree - Sure, we could use the name-number-field class instead, like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/7PhJZ/45/**

Comment: We are so close. but something still seems to get funky when I try turning it into a div. I updated this fiddle -----> http://jsfiddle.net/7PhJZ/48/

Comment: I add two to small and medium, good, I remove from small number input, the medium div's get removed.

Comment: @anmaree - you have some strange markup, try this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/7PhJZ/49/**

Comment: that did it! It works wonderfully now in my project. Thank you for you help, you have no idea how long I have struggled with this.